# Why am I getting this error in C? incompatible types

Tags: c, compiler-errors

15:9: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[3]’ from type ‘char *’

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     char servIP[3];
     int servPortNum;
     if(argc<3)
     {
         printf("Usage: clientApp servIP servPortNum\n");
     }

     servIP = argv[1];
     servPortNum = atoi(*argv[2]);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strncpy (servIP, argv [1], sizeof (servIP) - 1);
servIP [sizeof (servIP) - 1] = 0;
```

But are you sure `servIP` is big enough for an IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to arrays. Use `strcpy` or `strncpy` function to copy a string in an array of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`servIP` is an array, not a pointer. Arrays convert to pointers, but they aren't the same thing and pointers don't convert to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an array like this. Assign it member-by-member, or use `char *servIP` instead.